# Mayonnaise versus chicken spread

Tags: mayonnaise

Just confused is there any difference between mayo and chicken spread, what are the ingredients that make them different

Comment: Why not look at the ingredients list on the back of each? I've never heard of chicken spread… so unless it contains actual chicken...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not much alike.

Mayonnaise is made from oil (generally a neutral-tasting oil), an emulsifier (traditionally an egg yolk and some mustard), some acid (vinegar and lemon juice, e.g.), and some salt.

Chicken spread is made from chicken and fat and other ingredients, depending on the recipe. I've seen chicken spread recipes made with mayo as one of the fats (or all the fat).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Taste Of Home website where there are many recipes for Chicken Spread, mayonnaise is an ingredient used in chicken spread - which seems very similar to chicken salad as  we refer to it on the left side of the map. 
As near as I can tell, one is not a substitute for the other. :)